# How do I execute a C++ function asynchronously and not block/wait?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to execute a function asynchronously and not wait for it to complete. I initially thought I could use std::async with launch::async, but the returned future's destructor blocks until the function is complete.

Is there a way of running a function on a thread pool using stl without blocking?

Comment: What sort of function?  What does it do, for how long, and how many times and how frequently will you run it?

Comment: [std::thread::detach](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) may help.

Comment: @John Zwinck - The function does a background task that I don't want to hold the UI up with.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Maybe that will help. Will that spin up a new thread every time though. I thought std::async may use a pool of threads which I could make use of without needing to spin up a new thread and without needing to block.

Comment: @ScottLangham: you have neglected most of my clarifying questions.

Comment: And do you actually not care if it completes or not? For example if the user closes your app, do you want to just terminate the thread, or wait for it? I think you just want a simple thread, or thread pool, but not to actually abandon the thread.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Ok, yes: It's a C++ function. It sends a message to an RPC Server (and doesn't wait for a response). For how long, I'm not sure. It runs as often as the user selects to run it from the menu in the app, and it runs as many times as the user clicks the menu option.

Comment: @tenfour - I don't care if it completes. I may in the future get it to write any failure to a log file for purely diagnostic purposes. I don't need to feedback to the user whether it worked or not.

Comment: @tenfour - As I said to Jarod42, maybe it is sufficient :) I can't vote that as the answer though if it's not proposed as an answer. I did wonder though if that starts a new thread every time, or if there is a way of reusing a thread pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for std::thread::detach.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach

You can create a thread, and then detach from it.  At that point you can delete your thread handle and the thread will run without you.

Incidentally it's usually considered bad form to use this technique.  Generally you should care about the state of the thread, and should try to shut it down gracefully at program end, but in practice this is a useful trick for when you really don't care.

Answer (score 1):

You should spawn a single new thread which waits on a counting semaphore.  When it is awoken (unblocked), it will send one RPC request and decrement the counter.  When the user clicks the button, increment the counter.  The same thread can service all requests throughout the program's lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

This proposal talks about executors... it looks like the kind of thing I was hoping I'd find existed already, but it looks like it doesn't.

http://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4039.html